# HTML and CSS , position absolute question

Tags: html, css, position, positioning, css-position

Is it good and desirable to put all the web site content in a div with the following styling?

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%;">
        ALL site content come here
</div>
```

My problem is that i want to put in some places in the site divs that the width will be
100% without the spaces in the sides , so if i put all the site content in one absolutely div
and put a normal div with 100% width it will be from side to side without the spaces in the sides
example :

```
<div style="width:100%;background-color:yellow;"></div>
```

so , is that good to do that? and if it get some difficulties on the way?

Comment: You can do that without creating an absolutely positioned element. Put a `margin: 0; padding: 0` on your body element...

Comment: shouldn't you use instead the famous `*{margin:0; padding:0}`

Comment: :) @Mansuro, Do you ever really use that?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey well, what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are suggesting is safe, but you may accomplish what you want by adding `style="margin:0"` to your `<body>`. Or if you have a `.css` file, you can just add `body{margin:0}` to it. It would be simpler I think, but then, I am not sure whether I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Make that `margin:0px` - just `margin:0` only works in Quirks Mode.

Comment: That has not been my experience. However, I only work with standards-mode doctypes, Such as XHTML and HTML5. Also, I do not code for IE6. I would suggest to the reader to test on their site with their doctype and to test whichever browsers they are supporting.

Comment: works great ! more 6 minutes i will flag it as solved. btw a friend told me something about BLOCK element that will solve my problem as well , what did he mean?

Comment: @Kolink: Funny because the default/initial value for margin is listed as '0', not '0px'.

Comment: @Mor, I don't see how that solves your problem, but you should probably learn the difference between block-level and inline elements, for general knowledge.

Comment: Maybe 0 doesn't need a unit, then. But if it were 1 then you do need a unit. I just put the unit on all the time anyways.

Comment: @Kolink: Yes, any unit that is not 0 needs to have a 'px', 'em', or '%'. 0 is 0 no matter what unit is used, so we just say 0. :D